# Import data from Excel to SQL server with substring function in query

Tags: sql-server, excel, oledb

I am pretty much following the example on this MSDN page:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Imoprt-Data-from-Excel-to-705ecfcd

with 1 exception.  Instead of a simple query like

```
"Select * FROM [Sheet1$]"
```

I'd like to do something a little more complicated like:

```
"Select *, SUBSTRING(COLUMN_A, 1, 5) as STRIPPED_COL_A FROM [Sheet1$]"
```

but I'm getting a useless Exception message "IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)."

If I have to guess, the problem is due to the usage of the unsupported SUBSTRING function in Excel or OleDB.  So how to get around the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In their example you are using the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB driver to load the excel sheet via `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` or `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` so you are going to have to use the query formatting and functionality available within MS Access.

```
Select *, MID(Column_A, <<start>>, <<length>>) as STRIPPED_COL_A from [Sheet1$]
```

Keep in mind the other peculiarities such as `<<start>>` not being ZERO-indexed and instead starting with 1 being the first character in the string.